# How to change the type of a field?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to change the type of a field from within the mongo shell.

I am doing this...

```
db.meta.update(
  {'fields.properties.default': { $type : 1 }}, 
  {'fields.properties.default': { $type : 2 }}
)
```

But it's not working!

Comment: If anyone is in the same situation I was, having to `toString` some document's field, [here's the little program I've made/used](https://github.com/tallesl/mongo-to-string).

Answer (score 229, accepted):

The only way to change the `$type` of the data is to perform an update on the data where the data has the correct type.

In this case, it looks like you're trying to change the `$type` [from 1 (double) to 2 (string)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120505000412/http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24type).

So simply load the document from the DB, perform the cast (`new String(x)`) and then save the document again.

If you need to do this programmatically and entirely from the shell, you can use the `find(...).forEach(function(x) {})` syntax.

---

In response to the second comment below. Change the field `bad` from a number to a string in collection `foo`.

```
db.foo.find( { 'bad' : { $type : 1 } } ).forEach( function (x) {   
  x.bad = new String(x.bad); // convert field to string
  db.foo.save(x);
});
```

Comment: Any chance of an example - changing a field type from int to string (or vice versa), from the shell?

Comment: in case Int32->String, `new String(x.bad)` creates collection of Strings with 0-index-item `x.bad` value. Variant `""+x.bad`, described by Simone works as desired - creates String value instead of Int32

Comment: The above code is converting the field data from double to array instead of double to string. My actual data was in this format :3.1 whereas simone code is working fine for me

Comment: Had a situation where I needed to convert the _id field as well as not conflict with other indexes:
`db.questions.find({_id:{$type:16}}).forEach( function (x) {   
  db.questions.remove({_id:x._id},true);
  x._id = ""+x._id;
  db.questions.save(x);
});`

Comment: @SundarBons yes you are re-writing a field across your database, this is a big deal no matter how you do it. If you were using SQL and this was a big table  you would probably have to take some down time.

Comment: already use this, it will stop without completing all, I will not recommend this

Comment: IMO this should not be the accepted answer. The answer of Simone is the one that works. If you use `new String(obj.field)` you will get a dict and mess up your mongo collection.

Comment: Sadly, Simone's answer came about 6 months after mine. The only person who can change the "checkmark" is the original asker.

FWIW, they both use the same basic syntax, with Simone's addressing two very specific cases. I would not use any of these methods on a Production database with any amount of real data.

Comment: This works but damn! SOOOO SLOOOOOW! MongoDB needs to up its game with these kind of update operations. In SQL I could do an update that references values from the same row for thousands of records in only a few ms, like `UPDATE sometable SET name = CONCAT(first, ' ', last)` ... but in Mongo it's about the same time ... per record.

Comment: Yes, @ClubbedAce, it is very slow. You are effectively loading every entry in the collection and then re-saving this. I know it looks like you could do this quickly in SQL, but if you had a 3TB table, the change you list would likely lock the table and would also take a long a time.

To be clear, I would never use this method in a production database with any significant amount of data. If this data is actively being used, you need to migrate the data to a new field and update code, etc. Data safety is a lot of work.

Comment: `.save is not a function` facing this error

Answer (score 173):

Convert String field to Integer:

```
db.db-name.find({field-name: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) { 
    obj.field-name = new NumberInt(obj.field-name);
    db.db-name.save(obj);
});
```

Convert Integer field to String:

```
db.db-name.find({field-name: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.field-name = "" + obj.field-name;
    db.db-name.save(obj);
});
```

Comment: This is great - do you know how you'd convert a string (think currency like '1.23') to the integer 123?  I assume you'd have to parse it as a float or decimal, multiply it by 100, then save it as an integer, but I can't find the right docs to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually this working is good. But I have an application running with mongoid 2.4.0-stable which has fields such as field: customer_count, type: Integer & a validation as validates_numericality_of :customer_count which was working fine. Now when I am upgrading to mongoid to 3.0.16, when I assign a string value it automatically converts it to 0. without an error. I want to throw an error on wrong data assignment, this behavior turning out strange for me.

Comment: I ran this and got the error: Error: could not convert string to integer (shell):1

Comment: And if you need to convert string (or "normal" 32-bit integer) to 64-bit integer, use ```NumberLong``` as here:
```db.db-name.find({field-name : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { obj.field-name = new NumberLong(obj.field-name); db.db-name.save(obj); } );```

Comment: This worked for me not only for numbers but for ObjectId data types too.

Comment: Hello simone, I have tried this but it is not working for me. I am using mongodb 3.4 in linux 14 system.

Comment: "Convert Integer field to String:" works also for Double conversion to String

Answer (score 105):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update of a field based on its own value:

```
// { a: "45", b: "x" }
// { a:  53,  b: "y" }
db.collection.updateMany(
  { a : { $type: 1 } },
  [{ $set: { a: { $toString: "$a" } } }]
)
// { a: "45", b: "x" }
// { a: "53", b: "y" }
```

- The first part `{ a : { $type: 1 } }` is the match query:

  - It filters which documents to update.
  - In this case, since we want to convert `"a"` to string when its value is a double, this matches elements for which `"a"` is of type `1` (double)).
  - This [table](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/#available-types) provides the code representing the different possible types.
- The second part `[{ $set: { a: { $toString: "$a" } } }]` is the update aggregation pipeline:

  - Note the squared brackets signifying that this update query uses an aggregation pipeline.
  - [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator (`Mongo 4.2`) which in this case modifies a field.
  - This can be simply read as `"$set"` the value of `"a"` to `"$a"` converted `"$toString"`.
  - What's really new here, is being able in `Mongo 4.2` to reference the document itself when updating it: the new value for `"a"` is based on the existing value of `"$a"`.
  - Also note [`"$toString"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/#tostring-aggregation) which is a new aggregation operator introduced in `Mongo 4.0`.

---

In case your cast isn't from double to string, you have the choice between different conversion operators introduced in `Mongo 4.0` such as [`$toBool`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toBool/), [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/), ...

And if there isn't a dedicated converter for your targeted type, you can replace `{ $toString: "$a" }` with a `$convert` operation: `{ $convert: { input: "$a", to: 2 } }` where the value for `to` can be found in this [table](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/#available-types):

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { a : { $type: 1 } },
  [{ $set: { a: { $convert: { input: "$a", to: 2 } } } }]
)
```

Comment: `db.collection.updateMany(
  { a : { $type: 1 } },
  [{ $set: { a: { $toString: "$a" } } }]
)` - the `multi : true` can be avoided using `updateMany`

Comment: As of 2020, using $convert should be the correct method for this as it should be a lot more efficient (and easier to use to boot).

Comment: As of Mongo 4.0 there are shorthand operators:  "...In addition to $convert, MongoDB provides the following aggregation operators as shorthand when the default "onError" and "onNull" behavior is acceptable".  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#definition

Comment: This converted a double value of `6503856832666` to `"6.50386e+12"` :(

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal to convert a large double value to a string, avoiding scientific notation, you first have to convert it to a Long

Answer (score 47):

For string to int conversion.

```
db.my_collection.find().forEach( function(obj) {
    obj.my_value= new NumberInt(obj.my_value);
    db.my_collection.save(obj);
});
```

For string to double conversion.

```
    obj.my_value= parseInt(obj.my_value, 10);
```

For float:

```
    obj.my_value= parseFloat(obj.my_value);
```

Comment: I would recommend also specifying the `radix` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: **Watch out**, I tested this with Robomongo, and this resulted in type 1: double. Had to use `new NumberInt()`

Comment: Daniel, ur solution is not okay... david's solution is ok

Answer (score 29):

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function(data) {
    db.coll.update({_id:data._id},{$set:{myfield:parseInt(data.myfield)}});
})
```

Answer (score 21):

all answers so far use some version of forEach, iterating over all collection elements client-side.

However, you could use MongoDB's server-side processing by using aggregate pipeline and [$out stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#replace-existing-collection) as :

> the $out stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the
>   new results collection.

example:

```
db.documents.aggregate([
         {
            $project: {
               _id: 1,
               numberField: { $substr: ['$numberField', 0, -1] },
               otherField: 1,
               differentField: 1,
               anotherfield: 1,
               needolistAllFieldsHere: 1
            },
         },
         {
            $out: 'documents',
         },
      ]);
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't upvoted more.  Row by row operations on large data sets are murder on performance

Answer (score 12):

To convert a field of string type to date field, you would need to iterate the cursor returned by the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method using the **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method, within the loop convert the field to a Date object and then update the field using the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** operator.

Take advantage of using the **[Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** for bulk updates which offer better performance as you will be sending the operations to the server in batches of say 1000 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 1000 requests.

The following demonstrates this approach, the first example uses the Bulk API available in MongoDB versions `>= 2.6 and < 3.2`. It updates all
the documents in the collection by changing all the `created_at` fields to date fields:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.collection.find({"created_at": {"$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}).forEach(function (doc) {
    var newDate = new Date(doc.created_at);
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "created_at": newDate}
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(); // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})
// Clean up remaining operations in queue
if (counter % 1000 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

The next example applies to the new MongoDB version `3.2` which has since **[deprecated the Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api)** and provided a newer set of apis using **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)**:

```
var bulkOps = [];

db.collection.find({"created_at": {"$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}).forEach(function (doc) { 
    var newDate = new Date(doc.created_at);
    bulkOps.push(         
        { 
            "updateOne": { 
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id } ,              
                "update": { "$set": { "created_at": newDate } } 
            }         
        }           
    );     
})

db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps, { "ordered": true });
```

Comment: Great answer, the bulk method runs about 100x quicker for me even though it still appears to be a synchronous call.

Answer (score 3):

To convert int32 to string in mongo without creating an array **just add "" to your number** :-)

```
db.foo.find( { 'mynum' : { $type : 16 } } ).forEach( function (x) {   
  x.mynum = x.mynum + ""; // convert int32 to string
  db.foo.save(x);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

What really helped me to change the type of the object in MondoDB was just this simple line, perhaps mentioned before here...:

```
db.Users.find({age: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.age = new NumberInt(obj.age);
    db.Users.save(obj);
});
```

Users are my collection and age is the object which had a string instead of an integer (int32).

Answer (score 2):

```
You can easily convert the string data type to numerical data type.
Don't forget to change collectionName & FieldName.
for ex : CollectionNmae : Users & FieldName : Contactno.
```

Try this query..

```
db.collectionName.find().forEach( function (x) {
x.FieldName = parseInt(x.FieldName);
db.collectionName.save(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to change datatype of multiple fields in the collection, so I used the following to make multiple data type changes in the collection of documents. Answer to an old question but may be helpful for others.

```
db.mycoll.find().forEach(function(obj) { 

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('phone')) {
        obj.phone = "" + obj.phone;  // int or longint to string
    }

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('field-name')) {
     obj.field-name = new NumberInt(obj.field-name); //string to integer
    }

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('cdate')) {
        obj.cdate = new ISODate(obj.cdate); //string to Date
    }

    db.mycoll.save(obj); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

demo change type of field mid from string to mongo objectId using mongoose

```
 Post.find({}, {mid: 1,_id:1}).exec(function (err, doc) {
             doc.map((item, key) => {
                Post.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:item._id},{$set:{mid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.mid)}}).exec((err,res)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                    reply(res);
                });
            });
        });
```

Mongo ObjectId is just another example of such styles as

Number, string, boolean that hope the answer will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers almost worked but had a few challenges-

### Problem 1: `db.collection.save` no longer works in MongoDB 5.x

For this, I used `replaceOne()`.

### Problem 2: `new String(x.bad)` was giving exponential number

I used `"" + x.bad` as suggested above.

### My version:

```js
let count = 0;

db.user
    .find({
        custID: {$type: 1},
    })
    .forEach(function (record) {
        count++;

        const actualValue = record.custID;
        record.custID = "" + record.custID;
        console.log(`${count}. Updating User(id:${record._id}) from old id [${actualValue}](${typeof actualValue}) to [${record.custID}](${typeof record.custID})`)

        db.user.replaceOne({_id: record._id}, record);
    });
```

And for millions of records, here are the output (for future investigation/reference)-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use this script in mongodb console for string to float conversions...

```
db.documents.find({ 'fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
        obj.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.fwtweaeeba ); 
        db.documents.save(obj); } );    

db.documents.find({ 'versions.0.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
        obj.versions[0].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[0].content.fwtweaeeba ); 
        db.documents.save(obj); } );

db.documents.find({ 'versions.1.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
        obj.versions[1].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[1].content.fwtweaeeba );  
        db.documents.save(obj); } );

db.documents.find({ 'versions.2.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
        obj.versions[2].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[2].content.fwtweaeeba );  
        db.documents.save(obj); } );
```

And this one in php)))

```
foreach($db->documents->find(array("type" => "chair")) as $document){
    $db->documents->update(
        array('_id' => $document[_id]),
        array(
            '$set' => array(
                'versions.0.content.axdducvoxb' => (float)$document['versions'][0]['content']['axdducvoxb'],
                'versions.1.content.axdducvoxb' => (float)$document['versions'][1]['content']['axdducvoxb'],
                'versions.2.content.axdducvoxb' => (float)$document['versions'][2]['content']['axdducvoxb'],
                'axdducvoxb' => (float)$document['axdducvoxb']
            )
        ),
        array('$multi' => true)
    );


}
```