# Change type of field in Mongoid without losing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

How can I run a migration to change the type of a field in Mongoid/MongoDB without losing any data?

In my case I'm trying to convert from a BigDecimal (stored as string) to an Integer to store some money.  I need to convert the string decimal representation to cents for the integer.  I don't want to lose the existing data.

I'm assuming the steps might be something like:

1. create new Integer field with a new name, say `amount2`
2. deploy to production and run a migration (or rake task) that converts each `amount` to the right value for `amount2`
3. (this whole time existing code is still using `amount` and there is no downtime from the users perspective)
4. take the site down for maintenance, run the migration one more time to capture any `amount` fields that could have changed in the last few minutes
5. delete `amount` and rename `amount2` to `amount`
6. deploy new code which expects `amount` to be an integer
7. bring site back up

It looks like Mongoid offers a `rename` method: http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html#rename

But I'm a little confused how this is used.  If you have a field named `amount2` (and you've already deleted `amount`), do you just run `Transaction.rename :amount2, :amount`?  Then I imagine this immediately breaks the underlying representation so you have to restart your app server after that?  What happens if you run that while `amount` still exists?  Does it get overwritten, fail, or try to convert on it's own?

Thanks!

Comment: does sound logical. But I'm not sure whether you need restart or not. For one thing, you would need to update the field name in the model right?

As for overwrite, I'm not sure, but the upsert part of this link http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/how-to-rename-field-in-all-the-mongodb-documents/ does seem to suggest it will try to write, and optionally overwrite the field if it exists. So it's not like a regular SQL based rename, but rather moving each document value individually. Makes sense?

Comment: Hmm...not sure, would still like to get a working example from start to finish.  I'll post one if mine goes successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I made it through.  I think there is a faster way using the mongo console with something like this:
[MongoDB: How to change the type of a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field)

But I couldn't get the conversion working, so opted for this slower method in the rails console with more downtime.  If anyone has a faster solution please post it.

- create new Integer field with a new name, say `amount2`
- convert each `amount` to the right value for `amount2` in a console or rake task

```
Mongoid.identity_map_enabled = false
Transaction.all.each_with_index do |t,i|
  puts i if i%1000==0
  t.amount2 = t.amount.to_money
  break if !t.save
end
```

Note that .all.each works fine (you don't need to use .find_each or .find_in_batches like regular activerecord with mysql) because of mongodb cursors.  It won't fill up memory as long as the identity_map is off.

- take the site down for maintenance, run the migration one more time to capture any amount fields that could have changed in the last few minutes (something like `Transaction.where(:updated_at.gt => 1.hour.ago).each_with_index...`
- comment out `field :amount, type: BigDecimal` in your model, you don't want mongoid to know about this field anymore, and push this code
- now run another script to rename your column (it overwrites any old BigDecimal string values in the process).  You might need to comment any validations you have on the model which expect the old field.

```
Mongoid.identity_map_enabled = false
Transaction.all.each_with_index do |t,i|
  puts i if i%1000==0
  t.rename :amount2, :amount
end
```

This is atomic and doesn't require a save on the model.

- update your model to reflect the new column type `field :amount, type: Integer`
- deploy and bring the site back up

As mentioned I think there is a better way, so if anyone has some tips please share.  Thanks!

Comment: just a question. Any chance your cursor will timeout for large datasets?

Comment: yes, i think mongo's default cursor timeout is 10 minutes, can happen for sure.  if you can write it idempotently (check if amount2 is nil) and run it multiple times this might work.  Definitely seems harder than it should be though.

Comment: Update, I probably should have used this: https://github.com/nviennot/mongoid_lazy_migration  Looks easier than what I did

Comment: Ohh... I mostly followed your previous suggestion, working around the timeout. Thanks for sharing the gem