# Field with possible different types mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

In my model I have

```
field :is_open, type: Time, default: nil
```

However previously in this same model, I stored this type as a boolean. I now want to change it to type Time. For new items in my database this works fine, however for old records where it's still stored as a boolean, when I try to access this attribute

```
modelInstance.is_open
```

I get the following error:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `getlocal' for true:TrueClass>
```

Instead of changing all the booleans in my mongo database to Time objects, is there a way/hook I can do on mongo so that when this attribute is pulled from the document, I can check if it's a boolean and replace it with a timestamp?

Comment: Why don't you want to fix things inside MongoDB?

Comment: Eventually I will write a migration script, but for now I cannot change the format of my database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389548/change-type-of-field-in-mongoid-without-losing-data

Comment: @IS04 Yeah but that sort of violates the "cannot change the format of my database" restriction, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to specify the field type with Mongoid. That means that you can do things like this:

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :f
end
```

with data like this:

```
> db.models.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId(...), "f" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(...), "f" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(...), "f" : "pancakes" }
```

And everything will work out just fine:

```
rails > Model.all.map { |m| puts "#{m.f.class} - #{m.f.inspect}" }
TrueClass - true
Float - 6.0
String - "pancakes"
```

So you can drop the `:type` from your `field` and everything should work okay. Of course, you might want to provide your own `def is_open` and `def is_open=` methods if you need to do some sort of manual type conversion or checking while you're waiting to fix up your MongoDB data.