# Mongodb update query keeping the value and updating the datatype

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that has a key called called "code" and its value is sometimes a number with data-type new Mongoint32(5) and sometimes and string like "abcd". i have both values already in my database. What i want is to make them into single one ie a string. Is it possible to write and update query to make the mongoint32 type to string ?

thanks
hari krishna

Comment: which client lib are you using?

Comment: i am using mongodb 2.4, php 5 and ubuntu 64 bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to change the type of a field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the shell, you can do a find/forEach loop to update them.

To update the field named `value` in the collection `test` from int (type 1) to string, you can do;

```js
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b83850399aace88ba102d0"), "bop" : "olle", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b8385b399aace88ba102d2"), "bop" : "pelle" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b83860399aace88ba102d3"), "bop" : "kjell", "value" : "wow" }

> db.test.find({value: {$type:1}}).forEach(function(item) { 
                                     item.value=""+item.value; 
                                     db.test.save(item);
                                   });

{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b83850399aace88ba102d0"), "bop" : "olle", "value" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b8385b399aace88ba102d2"), "bop" : "pelle" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b83860399aace88ba102d3"), "bop" : "kjell", "value" : "wow" }
```

Comment: make `$type` as value `2`. As OP want form as `String`

Comment: i actually misunderstood `$type` is for converting to target type. Never mind

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joachim Isaksson answer, I would change the find() to use a query that finds only those documents that really contains that field (as you might have docs that don't have it - MongoDB is schemaless) and also, find only those docs that the relevant field type **is not** string.

sample:

```
// push few docs
db.so.insert({"a":1})
db.so.insert({"a":2})
db.so.insert({"a":"3"})
db.so.insert({"dontFindMe":4})

// this is the filter that make the different
db.so.find({$and:[{a:{$exists:true}},{a:{$not:{$type:2}}}]})
```

this will find only the relevant 2 documents and you'll avoid unnecessary update operations.
after you have the relevant docs in your hands, update them same as Joachim Isaksson explained.