# Mongodb update type of field

Tags: mongodb

I have following mongodb document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b73746485633a136000000"), "id_appointment" : 1602, "id_group" : "10", "action" : "SUPP", .....
```

I have to convert the field id_group into integer. How to do this on the command line?

Thank you for any help.
Andrea

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to change the type of a field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command from mongo command line:

```
db.MYCOLLECTION.find({ id_group: { $type: 2 } }).forEach(function(obj){
    try {
        obj.id_group = parseInt(obj.id_group);
        db.MYCOLLECTION.save(obj);
    } catch(e) {
        // do something with error...
    }
});
```

the `id_group: { $type: 2 }` tells mongo to load all the `id_group` which their value is a `string`.

You can find more about mongo types here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/#op._S_type