# Mongodb change field type

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, typeconverter

I had the problem with my query.
How can I do something like this SQL query in mongoDB query?

```
SELECT convert(datetime, field1)
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicly you cannot do it. While you cannot reference back a value inside a query you cannot convert it on the fly. You can update with a certain value if you know what you likely to put in. 
There is no such thing:

```
db.collection.update({},{$set:{b:ISODate('$b')}})
```

This is a current enhancement request.

The only way is to write a script which crawl through the collection save docs with the updated type . You also can run query based on the type of a field which may help if your flow brakes in between.

For this solution check that question : [MongoDB: How to change the type of a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field?rq=1)

The solution there is something like :

```
db.collection.find().forEach( function (x) {   
  x.b = new ISODate(x.b); // convert field to ISODate
  db.collection.save(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you need to convert a value stored in MongoDB, the only way to do it is in your application code. If this is a conversion that you need to do often and/or if you need to run queries on the converted values, you should consider storing both the original value *and* the converted value in the document. Denormalizations like this are very common in MongoDB schema design.