# Average a Sub Document Field Across Documents in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

For a given record id, how do I get the average of a sub document field if I have the following in MongoDB:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "item" : "1",
    "samples" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "test-key",
            "value" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "test-key2",
            "value" : "2"
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "item" : "1",
    "samples" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "test-key",
            "value" : "3"
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "test-key2",
            "value" : "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the average of the values where key = "test-key" for a given item id (in this case 1). So the average should be $avg (1 + 3) = 2

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to use the [aggregation framework.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) The aggregation will end up looking something like this:

```
db.stack.aggregate([
  { $match: { "samples.key" : "test-key" } },
  { $unwind : "$samples" },
  { $match : { "samples.key" : "test-key" } },
  { $project : { "new_key" : "$samples.key", "new_value" : "$samples.value" } },
  { $group : { `_id` : "$new_key", answer : { $avg : "$new_value" } } }
])
```

The best way to think of the aggregation framework is like an assembly line. The query itself is an array of JSON documents, where each sub-document represents a different step in the assembly.

### Step 1: $match

The first step is a basic filter, like a WHERE clause in SQL. We place this step first to filter out all documents that do not contain an array element containing `test-key`. Placing this at the beginning of the pipeline allows the aggregation to [use indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes).

### Step 2: $unwind

The second step, `$unwind`, is used for separating each of the elements in the "samples" array so we can perform operations across all of them. If you run the query with just that step, you'll see what I mean. 
Long story short :

```
{ name : "bob", 
  children : [ {"name" : mary}, { "name" : "sue" } ] 
}
```

becomes two documents :

```
{ name : "bob", children : [ { "name" : mary } ] }
{ name : "bob", children : [ { "name" : sue } ] }
```

### Step 3: $match

The third step, `$match`, is an exact duplicate of the first `$match` stage, but has a different purpose. Since it follows `$unwind`, this stage filters out previous array elements, now documents, that don't match the filter criteria. In this case, we keep only documents where `samples.key = "test-key"`

### Step 4: $project (Optional)

The fourth step, `$project`, restructures the document. In this case, I pulled the items out of the array so I could reference them directly. Using the example above..

```
{ name : "bob", children : [ { "name" : mary } ] }
```

becomes

```
{ new_name : "bob", new_child_name : mary }
```

Note that this step is entirely optional; later stages could be completed even without this `$project` after a few minor changes. In most cases `$project` is entirely cosmetic; aggregations have numerous optimizations under the hood such that manually including or excluding fields in a `$project` [should not be necessary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization).

### Step 5: $group

Finally, `$group` is where the magic happens. The `_id` value what you will be "grouping by" in the SQL world. The second field is saying to average over the value that I defined in the `$project` step. You can easily substitute `$sum` to perform a sum, but a count operation is typically done the following way: `my_count : { $sum : 1 }`.

The most important thing to note here is that the majority of the work being done is to format the data to a point where performing the operation is simple.

### Final Note

Lastly, I wanted to note that this would *not* work on the example data provided since `samples.value` is defined as text, which can't be used in arithmetic operations. If you're interested, changing the type of a field is described here: [MongoDB How to change the type of a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field)

Comment: thanks, that did the trick.  I also had to change the values to integers like you were saying.  would you mind explaining this query to me?  also, why doesn't samples.key have a $ in front of it on the $match line?  thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, i'll add explanation to the response above.

Comment: What if you do not know the object key values i.e.test-key and test-key2, but you do know that they will be consistent across documents? Is there a way to retrieve those first and then loop over them for example?

Comment: @user2576960 - I'm not sure I understand your question. The current aggregation includes $match statements on `test-key` to filter out data we don't want to consider. Are you saying that you want process all values of the array?