# GroupBy using cond to select fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to make a groupBy on mongoDB, using cond to select to appropriate field, however, mongo is giving me: "The field '$cond' must be an accumulator object"

```
$group{
 "_id" : {"dateId" : "$dateId"},
 "estimated" : { "$sum" : "$estimated_records"},
 $cond: {
   if:  {"activeSelfConsumption" : {"$exists" : true}} , (I'm also not sure if this work)
   then : {"value" : { "$sum" :"$activeSelfConsumption"}}, 
   else : {"value" : { "$sum" :"$active"}} }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongo group and count with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169115/mongo-group-and-count-with-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator is not required. Use [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) instead.

Something like

```
{"$group":{
 "_id" : {"dateId":"$dateId"},
 "estimated":{"$sum":"$estimated_records"},
 "value":{"$sum":{"$ifNull":['$activeSelfConsumption','$active']}}
}}
```

Comment: thanks, yeah, I used exactly that query a few hours after I post the question.