# how to count rows based on different condition in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that contains an age column, is it possible to count the number of rows that have age column lower than for example 10, between 10 and 30 and upper than 30 in one query?
i.e. output be something like this:

```
age             cnt
<=10            607
10< and < 30    304
>=30            405
```

Comment: Post about [mongo group and count with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169115/mongo-group-and-count-with-condition). Documentation on [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo group and count with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169115/mongo-group-and-count-with-condition) making it a duplicate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I post the answer may be helpful to someone!) As prasad_ said you can achieve this by using

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            item: 1,
            lessThan10: {  
                $cond: [ { $lt: ["$dob.age", 10 ] }, 1, 0]
            },
            moreThan10lessThan30: {  
                $cond: [ { $and: [ { $gte: ["$dob.age", 10 ] }, { $lte: ["$dob.age", 30 ] } ] }, 1, 0]
            },
            morethan30:{
                $cond: [{ $gt: ["$dob.age", 30]}, 1, 0]
            }


        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$item",
            lessthan10: { $sum: "$lessThan10" },
            between10and30: { $sum: "$moreThan10lessThan30" },
            morethan30:{$sum:"$morethan30"}

        }
    }
])
```