# Mongoose - filter matched documents and assign the resultant length to a field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this collection(some irrelevant fields were omitted for brevity):

```js
clients: {
  userId: ObjectId,
  clientSalesValue: Number,
  currentDebt: Number,  
}
```

Then I have this query that matches all the clients for a specific user, then calculates the sum of all debts and sales and put those results in a separate field each of them:

```js
await clientsCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { userId: new ObjectId(userId) }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalSalesValue: { $sum: '$clientSalesValue' },
      totalDebts: { $sum: '$currentDebt' },
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: ['_id']
  }
]).exec();
```

This works as expected, it returns an array with only one item which is an object, but now I need to also include in that resultant object a field for the amount of debtors, that is for the amount of clients that have `currentDebt` > 0, how can I do that is the same query? is it possible?

PD: I cannot modify the `$match` condition, it need to always return **all** the clients for the corresponding users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group and count with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169115/group-and-count-with-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include a count of how many matching documents have a positive `currentDebt`, you can use the `$sum` and `$cond` operators like so:

```js
await clientsCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { userId: new ObjectId(userId) }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalSalesValue: { $sum: '$clientSalesValue' },
      totalDebts: { $sum: '$currentDebt' },
      numDebtors: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $gt: ['$currentDebt', 0] }, 1, 0]
        }
      }, 
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: ['_id']
  }
]).exec();
```