# mongodb descendent sorting by a numeric field getting sorted randomly (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, database

I have a mongo database running in cmd.
There is a collection named usercollection.
And there is also some documents which I'm getting by typing in mongo shell:

```
db.usercollection.find().sort({score: -1}).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{                                                                 
        "_id" : ObjectId("57501b2d7ef17cd8c1bd63bc"),             
        "name" : "QWERTY",                                        
        "score" : "100",                                          
        "link" : "http://qwerty.com"                              
}                                                                 
{                                                                 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5750199819433f80da88c847"),             
        "name" : "Adam Sandler",                                  
        "score" : "222",                                          
        "link" : "http://sandler.com"                             
}                                                                 
{                                                                 
        "_id" : ObjectId("57501af57ef17cd8c1bd63bb"),             
        "name" : "gfhfghfghguy",                                      
        "score" : "5",                                            
        "link" : "http://dsad.com"                                
}                                                                 
{                                                                 
        "_id" : ObjectId("57501bb47ef17cd8c1bd63bd"),             
        "name" : "Test name",                                     
        "score" : "50",                                           
        "link" : "http://fdsfds.cpm"                              
}                                                                 
{                                                                 
        "_id" : ObjectId("574f4a9dab868fdc896d11b4"),             
        "name" : "Rich Man",                                      
        "score" : "500",                                          
        "link" : "http://jikl.me"                              
}                                                                 
{                                                                 
        "_id" : ObjectId("574f50f1fbd256888ffa248d"),             
        "name" : "lfgfgff",                                   
        "score" : "9",                                            
        "link" : "http://oh.com"                                  
}                                                                 
{                                                                 
        "_id" : ObjectId("574f5324fbd256888ffa248e"),             
        "name" : "test name",                                     
        "score" : "9",                                            
        "link" : "http://dsad.com"                                
}
```

The problem is that I'm trying to sort these documents from one with highest score to one with lowest score and it's output is completely random(

I'm displaying that documents on the website using node.js and the result is the same as in the console.

Comment: The problem is that your `score` values are strings, not numbers. It would be best to store it as a number instead.

Comment: I'm new to that stuff, can u tell me how to make it numbers?

Comment: You can convert using an approach like http://stackoverflow.com/a/9746195/1259510

Comment: okay, but if I'll add new documents from my website, I'll need to do converting after every adding?

Comment: No, you'd want to change your code to ensure you've converted those fields to a numeric type before adding the document.

Comment: can you tell me how can I do it in node? 
var score = req.body.score;
I have an insert function:
collection.insert({
        "score" : score,

Comment: I've done it. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
db.usercollection.find().sort({score: 'desc'}).pretty()
```

Comment: Error:
"waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "bad sort specification",
        "code" : 2