# Summation of sub document field based on a group unexpected behaviour

Tags: mongodb-query

```
*I have a document structured in which we embedded the salary Document into  the Employee_Detail Document.As per the MongoDb documantation ,we can use $Unwind to deconstruct the Document and use aggregated pipeline...But its not working. i am using the below script...*    
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5763d4a54da83b98f269878a"),  
    "First_Name" : "fgfg", 
    "Department" : "QA", 
    "Salary" : {
        "HRA" : "1200", 
        "Basic" : "2000", 
    }

})  
And i want to get sum of basic salary based on department Like
```

then Expected output is
  Department    Total_Basic**
      QA             2000

```
I have used the following code to get the output. I have used the $unwind to     deconstruct the document.and use aggregated pipeline to group the department(Sum of basic Salary).

db.Employee_Detail.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$Salary"},   {$group: {"_id": "$Department", total_Basic: {$sum: "$Salary.Basic" }
    }}
])    
But i get the below Result.   
Department    Total_Basic
QA             0
```

I think $unwind is not Working. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is the type of the field `Basic` is a string. Second, you do not need to use unwind unless the field `Salary` contains an array.

So perform an update to convert the types of `Basic` and `HRA` to floats, ([see this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field))

And then an aggregate operation like this will give you the desired result:

```
db.Employee_Detail.aggregate([
    {$group: {"_id": "$Department", total_Basic: {$sum: "$Salary.Basic" }}
])
```