# How do I convert all geo locations in mongo db from strings to floats?

Tags: mongodb

```
skatespot-dev> db.parks.findOne();
{
  _id: ObjectId("638f9866d9014fabfc47275e"),
  address: '801 Pine St, Anchorage, AK',
  name: 'Russian Jack Skatepark',
  location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ '61.214855', '-149.793563' ] }
}
```

I need to run a query to convert all coodinates to floats i guess.

Comment: This is looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942844/mongodb-convert-string-type-to-float-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert them to double using [update with pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "location.coordinates": [
        {
          $toDouble: {
            $first: "$location.coordinates"
          }
        },
        {
          $toDouble: {
            $last: "$location.coordinates"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bWCr69yd0q2)