# Is it possible to compare string with ObjectId via $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

`table1` has a field string "value" and `table2` has a field "value" as `ObjectId`, Is it possible to do a query like this or how to write

```
table1.aggregate([
    { 
        $lookup: { 
            from: "table2", 
            localField: "value", 
            foreignField: "_id", 
            as: "test" 
        }  
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

As far I know to join collections using `$lookup` operator in **MongoDB** data type should be same. If type mismatch then `$lookup` will not work. So to join you should use those field that are *same type* because it check **equality**.

> The $lookup stage does an equality match between a field from the
>   input documents with a field from the documents of the “joined”
>   collection

- If *localField* type `object` then *foreignField* should be `object`
- If *localField*  type `string` then *foreignField*  should be `string`
- If *localField*  type `number` then *foreignField*  should be `number`

[$lookup Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-aggregation)

Comment: is it possible to temporarily convert string to object for checking

Comment: can visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field