# How to return all documents in Mongo db collection that does not contain a long type in an array, and change those element's type

Tags: arrays, mongodb, types, find

So I have a mongo database with collections that have fields set to a type of array.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("kdsfisdasg924837529dsfhk"),
    "myArr" : [ 
        123456
    ]
}
```

I'm looking to query this collection and find all documents, that do not have the elements in `myArr` set to a data type of long. I've been digging around, and I haven't found anything referencing a solution. I was trying something like:
`db.myCollection.find({myArr: {$not: {$type: "long"}}},{myArr:1, _id: 0})`

If i pass `.count()` to it, it returns a large number of documents. Almost the entire collection's document count, which I know is incorrect. I'm guessing I'm using `$not` incorrectly. Is my syntax wrong? is there a different approach to solving this?

**UPDATE**

I believe I have solved the problem of finding the documents that have arrays without elements of the type `long` using: `db.myCollection.find({myArr: {$elemMatch: {$not: {$type: "long"}}}}, {myArr:1, _id: 0})`. How would one go about recasting or changing all those element's types to `long`?

**For Refernce**

Im getting pretty close. I believe I can modify this function I wrote to iterate over the array thats within the documents returned with the above function.

```
db.myCollection.find({myArr: {$elemMatch: {$not: {$type: 18}}}}).forEach(function(myDoc){
    for(var i =0; i < myDoc.myArr.length; i++){
        print(typeof myDoc.myArr[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried anding in `$exists` and `$not: $type: "undefined"` as well, but it returned the same `count()`

Comment: I believe I found my solution. looks like i needed $elemMatch as follows, to iterate over the array elements:
`db.myCollection.find({myArr: {$elemMatch: {$not: {$type: "long"}}}}, {myArr:1, _id: 0}).count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHA! Got it! Thanks to [Simone's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999501/simone) and [GatesVP's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261188/gates-vp) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4973632/7740139)

```
db.myCollection.find({myArr: {$elemMatch: {$not: {$type: 18}}}}).forEach(function(myDoc){
    for(var i =0; i < myDoc.myArr.length; i++){
        myDoc.myArr[i] = NumberLong(myDoc.myArr[i]);
        db.transactions.save(myDoc);
    }
});
```

I double checked by using MongoDB's compass GUI client and it shows all instances of `myArr` now contain nothing but `long` values in its elements. I also removed the `$not` logic in the previous `find` in the CLI client to make sure the data's value was preserved. looking good. Also printed the json for the last 3 results of that `find` command to take a peek inside each of the docs at how it was structured.

```
db.myCollection.find({myArr: {$elemMatch: {$type: 18}}}).sort({$natural: -1}).limit(3).forEach(printjson);
```