# How to parseFloat in a bulk update Mongo operation

Tags: mongodb

So I have a few fields that are currently strings that I am converting over to Double values in my mongo database. I was originally doing it with a find.forEach(function()).... style but that was taking way too long so I decided to try out the bulk operations Mongo has. So here is my attempt:

```
var bulkOp = db.transactions.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulkOp.find({"tran.val": {$exists: true}}).update(
    {
      $set: {"tran.val":parseFloat("$tran.val")}
    }
);
bulkOp.execute();
```

When I do this my tran.val which use to be "1.35" or something along those lines now becomes NaN. I also tried without the $ on tran.val but no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: Tried NumberDecimal("$tran.val") instead and got:    Error: Input is not a valid Decimal128 value.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945977/2683814) as how to use bulk write and use NumberDecimal to convert values.