# How can we update Array object value in MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i want to update my all MongoDB doc who contain ObjectId in my nested array object

my doc is:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a61a6bdae8bdc26685f8c27"), 
  "variant_count" : 1, 
  "salts" : [
    {
        "name" : "Cetirizine", 
        "classification" : "HD", 
        "dosage" : 0.0, 
        "is_cold_storage" : false, 
        "id" : ObjectId("5a61a292ae8bdc26685f2a91")
    }]
  "drug_category" : "DRUGS", 
  "name" : "Adicold Tab", 

}
```

i want to update all salts.id as a string,

for eg.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a61a6bdae8bdc26685f8c27"), 
  "variant_count" : 1, 
  "salts" : [
    {
        "name" : "Cetirizine", 
        "classification" : "HD", 
        "dosage" : 0.0, 
        "is_cold_storage" : false, 
        "id" : "5a61a292ae8bdc26685f2a91"
    }]
  "drug_category" : "DRUGS", 
  "name" : "Adicold Tab", 
}
```

Comment: You can change it as you will change any other field type. The below link will provide you the solution. Just use field name as salts.id.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field

Comment: Thanks @Novice it helps me to solve my issue, also posting update query for same, please review, if any other optimization required please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is works for me:

```
db.product.find({"salts.id" : {$type : 7}}).forEach(
    function(doc) {
    var salts = doc.salts;
    var newSalts = [];
    if (Array.isArray(salts) && salts.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < salts.length; i++) { 
        salt = salts[i];
        if (salt['id'] != null && typeof salt['id'] == 'object') {
            salt['id'] = salt['id'].str
            newSalts.push(salt)
        } else {
          newSalts.push(salt)
        }
      } 
      db.product.update( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { salts: newSalts } } 
     );
      i = i + 1;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: If this works for you, please carry on. I don't think any optimization is needed as this update will be run only once. It is not a recurring function. But yes, if you planning to run it in production DB and it was not a mandatory field, I would suggest you run some tests first, especially with variations of 'no such field in the collection', 'field assigned null rather than undefined ' etc.Is there really a reason to update it ? Coz most of the drivers provide a string representation of the Object ID, for your .net driver, its just an annotation over the variable.

Comment: Ah ok. Well, I will suggest you run some tests. Also, don't think you need the else part. If the id is present, change it to string and call update. Good luck !!

Answer (score -1):

```
**This code is working fine for me.**

db.collectionName.find({}).forEach(function(item){
                    if (item) {
                        item.salts.forEach(function(data){ 
                            if(data){
                                data.id = data.id.valueOf();
                            }
                        })
                        db.collectionName.save(item);
                    }
                })
```