# How to convert string to double in mongoid aggregate on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aggregation-framework

Here is ruby code

```
 currency_conversion_rate = {
  "$project" => {
    'conversion_rate': '$conversion_rate',
  }
}
```

`$conversion_rate` is string type float number like `66.57`. I have tried one method to use `'$conversion_rate'.to_f` but that makes it `0.0`, other in mind is to somehow use `parseFlaot`, that I don't know yet how to use.

Other Details:

```
rails -> 5.0.2
mongoid -> 6.0.3
mongo -> 3.6.5
```

Comment: You didn't provide any line of code where `to_f` method is used. We need more information, how and where did you try to use it? Please, update your question with more details.

Comment: Provided additional details thanks for constructive feedback. I am trying to use `parseDouble` somehow, I am going through manual maybe I get something

Comment: Doesn't that just mean that you're storing `conversion_rate` as a string? If you save your values as the correct type (float or decimal) this problem wouldn't be happening. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973095/3982562

Comment: yeah, for now we migrated that value to new attribute where all values are stored as double

Answer (score 0):

Due to your question I only have one answer for you

You don't call the `to_f` on a string number like `"66.57".to_f`. You are calling `.to_f` on just a simple string `"$conversion_rate".to_f` which is simply `0.0`. It is like `"foobar".to_f`

If you have `$conversion_rate` as variable you should use it correctly.

```
currency_conversion_rate = {
  "$project" => {
    'conversion_rate': $conversion_rate,
  }
}
```

or as alternative, although ugly code

```
currency_conversion_rate = {
  "$project" => {
    'conversion_rate': "#{$conversion_rate}",
  }
}
```

Comment: definitely your first point is right, I also checked it. But solution didn't worked `$conversion_rate` outputs `null` and `"#{$conversion_rate}"` outputs empty string. I think solution should be something that can process it on runtime like other operators `"$eq", "$multiply"`

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11400 this issue talks about operators to convert. I doubt why it is closed when solution is not yet implemented.

Comment: Well then... Do you use `Modelname.collection.aggragate(currency_conversion_rate)`?

Comment: I am using `Modelname.collection.aggregate( {"$match"}, conversion_rate, ..)` in conversion rate is problem, it is string type and I need it in double. I don't know how `Modelname.collection.aggragate(currency_conversion_rate)` can help