# Extremely slow Date range query in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I developed the application through Mongoose and my query (below) to be 30s to 60s slow.

`Transaction.find({code: '0001', time: {$lte: new Date(2018-01-02), $gt: new Date(2018-01-01)}});`

Then I tested with mongo shell with the query (below) didn't seem to help.

```
db.Transaction.find({code: '0001', time: { $lte: '2018-01-02T00:00:00Z', $gt: '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z'}});`
```

Below are my .explains as well as the collection's stats.

Transaction's stats

```
{
    "ns" : "TickData.transactions",
    "size" : 6779402152,
    "count" : 72038705,
    "avgObjSize" : 94,
    "storageSize" : 2113564672,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : {
        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 1
        },
        "creationString" : "access_pattern_hint=none,allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),assert=(commit_timestamp=none,read_timestamp=none),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=snappy,cache_resident=false,checksum=on,colgroups=,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,encryption=(keyid=,name=),exclusive=false,extractor=,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,ignore_in_memory_cache_size=false,immutable=false,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=true,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=64MB,log=(enabled=true),lsm=(auto_throttle=true,bloom=true,bloom_bit_count=16,bloom_config=,bloom_hash_count=8,bloom_oldest=false,chunk_count_limit=0,chunk_max=5GB,chunk_size=10MB,merge_custom=(prefix=,start_generation=0,suffix=),merge_max=15,merge_min=0),memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=false,prefix_compression_min=4,source=,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,type=file,value_format=u",
        "type" : "file",
        "uri" : "statistics:table:collection-12--503685154145610087",
        "LSM" : {
            "bloom filter false positives" : 0,
            "bloom filter hits" : 0,
            "bloom filter misses" : 0,
            "bloom filter pages evicted from cache" : 0,
            "bloom filter pages read into cache" : 0,
            "bloom filters in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "chunks in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "highest merge generation in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "queries that could have benefited from a Bloom filter that did not exist" : 0,
            "sleep for LSM checkpoint throttle" : 0,
            "sleep for LSM merge throttle" : 0,
            "total size of bloom filters" : 0
        },
        "block-manager" : {
            "allocations requiring file extension" : 0,
            "blocks allocated" : 0,
            "blocks freed" : 0,
            "checkpoint size" : 2113531904,
            "file allocation unit size" : 4096,
            "file bytes available for reuse" : 16384,
            "file magic number" : 120897,
            "file major version number" : 1,
            "file size in bytes" : 2113564672,
            "minor version number" : 0
        },
        "btree" : {
            "btree checkpoint generation" : 294,
            "column-store fixed-size leaf pages" : 0,
            "column-store internal pages" : 0,
            "column-store variable-size RLE encoded values" : 0,
            "column-store variable-size deleted values" : 0,
            "column-store variable-size leaf pages" : 0,
            "fixed-record size" : 0,
            "maximum internal page key size" : 368,
            "maximum internal page size" : 4096,
            "maximum leaf page key size" : 2867,
            "maximum leaf page size" : 32768,
            "maximum leaf page value size" : 67108864,
            "maximum tree depth" : 5,
            "number of key/value pairs" : 0,
            "overflow pages" : 0,
            "pages rewritten by compaction" : 0,
            "row-store internal pages" : 0,
            "row-store leaf pages" : 0
        },
        "cache" : {
            "bytes currently in the cache" : 1264186983,
            "bytes read into cache" : NumberLong("1641469097316"),
            "bytes written from cache" : 0,
            "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 0,
            "data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 310,
            "eviction walk passes of a file" : 1193252,
            "eviction walk target pages histogram - 0-9" : 3707,
            "eviction walk target pages histogram - 10-31" : 1969,
            "eviction walk target pages histogram - 128 and higher" : 0,
            "eviction walk target pages histogram - 32-63" : 3261,
            "eviction walk target pages histogram - 64-128" : 1184315,
            "eviction walks abandoned" : 16565,
            "eviction walks gave up because they restarted their walk twice" : 0,
            "eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found no candidates" : 1576,
            "eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found too few candidates" : 1464,
            "eviction walks reached end of tree" : 16287,
            "eviction walks started from root of tree" : 19605,
            "eviction walks started from saved location in tree" : 1173647,
            "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 205,
            "in-memory page passed criteria to be split" : 0,
            "in-memory page splits" : 0,
            "internal pages evicted" : 150133,
            "internal pages split during eviction" : 0,
            "leaf pages split during eviction" : 0,
            "modified pages evicted" : 0,
            "overflow pages read into cache" : 0,
            "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
            "page written requiring lookaside records" : 0,
            "pages read into cache" : 57616140,
            "pages read into cache requiring lookaside entries" : 0,
            "pages requested from the cache" : 442748265,
            "pages seen by eviction walk" : 131524175,
            "pages written from cache" : 0,
            "pages written requiring in-memory restoration" : 0,
            "tracked dirty bytes in the cache" : 0,
            "unmodified pages evicted" : 57575155
        },
        "cache_walk" : {
            "Average difference between current eviction generation when the page was last considered" : 0,
            "Average on-disk page image size seen" : 0,
            "Average time in cache for pages that have been visited by the eviction server" : 0,
            "Average time in cache for pages that have not been visited by the eviction server" : 0,
            "Clean pages currently in cache" : 0,
            "Current eviction generation" : 0,
            "Dirty pages currently in cache" : 0,
            "Entries in the root page" : 0,
            "Internal pages currently in cache" : 0,
            "Leaf pages currently in cache" : 0,
            "Maximum difference between current eviction generation when the page was last considered" : 0,
            "Maximum page size seen" : 0,
            "Minimum on-disk page image size seen" : 0,
            "Number of pages never visited by eviction server" : 0,
            "On-disk page image sizes smaller than a single allocation unit" : 0,
            "Pages created in memory and never written" : 0,
            "Pages currently queued for eviction" : 0,
            "Pages that could not be queued for eviction" : 0,
            "Refs skipped during cache traversal" : 0,
            "Size of the root page" : 0,
            "Total number of pages currently in cache" : 0
        },
        "compression" : {
            "compressed pages read" : 57456583,
            "compressed pages written" : 0,
            "page written failed to compress" : 0,
            "page written was too small to compress" : 0,
            "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : 0,
            "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : 0,
            "raw compression call succeeded" : 0
        },
        "cursor" : {
            "bulk-loaded cursor-insert calls" : 0,
            "create calls" : 3,
            "cursor-insert key and value bytes inserted" : 0,
            "cursor-remove key bytes removed" : 0,
            "cursor-update value bytes updated" : 0,
            "insert calls" : 0,
            "modify calls" : 0,
            "next calls" : 16369888007,
            "prev calls" : 1,
            "remove calls" : 0,
            "reserve calls" : 0,
            "reset calls" : 127918738,
            "restarted searches" : 0,
            "search calls" : 0,
            "search near calls" : 127899373,
            "truncate calls" : 0,
            "update calls" : 0
        },
        "reconciliation" : {
            "dictionary matches" : 0,
            "fast-path pages deleted" : 0,
            "internal page key bytes discarded using suffix compression" : 0,
            "internal page multi-block writes" : 0,
            "internal-page overflow keys" : 0,
            "leaf page key bytes discarded using prefix compression" : 0,
            "leaf page multi-block writes" : 0,
            "leaf-page overflow keys" : 0,
            "maximum blocks required for a page" : 0,
            "overflow values written" : 0,
            "page checksum matches" : 0,
            "page reconciliation calls" : 0,
            "page reconciliation calls for eviction" : 0,
            "pages deleted" : 0
        },
        "session" : {
            "object compaction" : 0,
            "open cursor count" : 3
        },
        "transaction" : {
            "update conflicts" : 0
        }
    },
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 732811264,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 732811264
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Transaction's query's explain()

```
> db.transactions.find({code:'0001',time: {$gte:ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00Z"),$lte:ISODate("2018-07-05T00:00:00Z")}}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "TickData.transactions",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "code" : {
                        "$eq" : "0001"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "time" : {
                        "$lte" : ISODate("2018-07-05T00:00:00Z")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "time" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "code" : {
                            "$eq" : "0001"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "time" : {
                            "$lte" : ISODate("2018-07-05T00:00:00Z")
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "time" : {
                            "$gte" : ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00Z")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.3",
        "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.transactions.find({code:'0001',time: {$gte:ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00Z"),$lte:ISODate("2018-07-05T00:00:00Z")}}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "TickData.transactions",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "code" : {
                        "$eq" : "0001"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "time" : {
                        "$lte" : ISODate("2018-07-05T00:00:00Z")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "time" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "code" : {
                            "$eq" : "0001"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "time" : {
                            "$lte" : ISODate("2018-07-05T00:00:00Z")
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "time" : {
                            "$gte" : ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00Z")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.3",
        "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

How can I improve the query performances?

Comment: Have you created indexes? "winningPlan" says "COLLSCAN", it seems you haven't. Also, I think in your query you should use `$gte` on the lower date (2018-01-01) and `$lt` on the maximum date (2018-01-02), otherwise you could miss records from 01-01 and include records from 01-02.

Comment: Creating a indexes, the winningPlan still show "COLLSCAN".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query performs a Collection scan - which means it will scan all the item in the collection in order to retrieve the results.

You can use indices to improve the query time, create index on both `code` field, as well as on `time` field.

Use the following line to do so:

```
db.Transaction.createIndex( { code: 1, time: 1})
```

Comment: God damn it! It's now lightning fast!

Answer (score 0):

1) Add indexing of fields on which you want to get performance boost while querying may be helpful. 
You can read more about mongoDB indexes [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).

2) If you do not need BSON data type advantages while operating with query output data - you could `lean` mongoose query. This will increase performance too. Like this:

```
Transaction.find({
  code: "0001",
  time: { $lte: new Date("2018-01-02"), $gt: new Date("2018-01-01") }
}).lean();
```

P.S.
If you have to process large datasets programmatically - it will be better to perform this in batches.

Comment: Great comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slow date comparison queries may also result from having stored dates as strings.

There are multiple ways to convert the type of a field, but here is one. Others are discussed here (see Xavier Guihot's answer): [How to change the type of a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field)

```
db.collection.updateMany({ a : { $type: 1 } },
  [{ $set: { a: { $convert: { input: "$a", to: 2 } } } }]
);
```

Depending on your target data type, the value of **to** (in this case, 2) can be found in the table available at this link:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/#available-types