# How To Change Datatype String To Number of particular field in collection of mongo using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
[{
      "id": 5f6af7bd3f06d50018f28680,
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51FQpz-zY1L._SL1024_.jpg",
      "name": "Mac book",
      "price": "150",
      "description": "Apple MacBook Air",
      "rating": 4,
    },
    {
      "id": 5f6af7bd3f06d50018f28682,
      "image": "https://static.acer.com/up/Resource/Acer/Laptops/Swift_7",
      "name": "Dell Laptop",
      "price": "250",
      "description": "Find solace in your love for riding when you cruise",
      "rating": 4,
    }]
```

In This I want to Change Datatype Of All Object of json Mongodb which is price.

Actually Price is String But i want to convert it to Number dynamically.

Comment: It would help if you could provide some code showing how you are getting the JSON object you provided, and what code in node is "dynamically" handling said JSON. Without that it's hard to provide a good solution that fits your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.my_collection.find({price: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.price = new NumberInt(obj.price);
  db.my_collection.save(obj);
});
```

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field

Comment: db.my_collection.find(...).forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = my_schema.find();
data.map((item) => {
    my_schema.findOneAndUpdate({_id: item._id}, {price: Number(item.price)}})
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you correctly , you retrieve array of object from db where pricing field is string and after it you need convert it to numbers ?

1. Why just not store it as number ?
2. You can convert it use .map function just after retrieve or if you use mongoose you can do it in post hook in same way.

Comment: simple i want to sort by price but price is string it cant sort properly advice me

Comment: You are getting Can't cast number  when execute insert to db ?

Comment: If it is already stored in db as string and you need do search by it , as solution you can use aggregation framework , and do projection from string to number as first step and after do search. But my main question why you need store as string in db if price it is number

Comment: about aggregation ?