# Is it possible to change object types in MongoDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, integer

When I uploaded a CSV file to MongoDB, one of the objects I chose as a number, but they came out to be Doubles. This later caused some issues and I don't want to reupload the CSV file. Is there an easy way to change Doubles into Int64s for one data type in Python3?

Comment: Python doesn't tell a difference between the two, you can use numpy to set a precision for C like numbers, are you meaning to change the data as it stored in DynamoDB or after you have got it from there?

Comment: I had the original file as a csv and then I had it uploaded to MongoDB using the Compass tool.

Comment: DynamoDB?? I'm using MongoDB.

Comment: Sorry, do you want the type to change in MongoDB or in your code?

Comment: I want to change it in MongoDB.

Comment: I found this answer, does it answer your case?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4973632/14273548