# Proper way to convert Data type of a field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

Possible Replication of [How to change the type of a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field)

I am currently newly learning MongoDB and I am facing problem while converting Data type of  field value to another data type.

Below is an example of my document

```
[
{
   
    "Name of Restaurant": "Briyani Center",
    "Address": " 336 & 338, Main Road",
    "Location": "XYZQWE",
    "PriceFor2": "500.0",
    "Dining Rating": "4.3",
    "Dining Rating Count": "1500",
},
{
    "Name of Restaurant": "Veggie Conner",
    "Address": " New 14, Old 11/3Q, Railway Station Road",
    "Location": "ABCDEF",
    "PriceFor2": "1000.0",
    "Dining Rating": "4.4",
    
}]
```

Like above I have 12k documents. Notice the datatype of PriceFor2 is a ***string***. I would like to ***convert*** the data type to ***Integer data type***.

I have referred many amazing answers given in the above link. But when I try to run the query, I get ***.save() is not a function error***. Please advice what is the problem.

Below is the code I used

```
db.chennaiData.find().forEach( function(x){ x.priceFor2= new NumberInt(x.priceFor2);
db.chennaiData.save(x);
db.chennaiData.save(x);});
```

This is the error I am getting..

```
TypeError: db.chennaiData.save is not a function
```

Comment: Anything not working in the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56570099/14732669) from your provided link? It is also more performant as it perform only one db call.

Comment: nope @ray, I keep getting .save is not a function error... What might be the reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MongoDB's [save](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/db.collection.save/) documentation:

> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, the
> db.collection.save()
> method is deprecated. Use db.collection.insertOne() or db.collection.replaceOne() instead.

Likely you are having a MongoDB with version 4.2+, so the `save` function is no longer available. Consider migrate to the usage of `insertOne` and `replaceOne` as suggested.

---

For your specific scenario, it is actually preferred to do with a single `update` as mentioned in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56570099/14732669). It only does one db call(while your approach fetches all documents in the collection to the application level) and performs n db call to save them back.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      PriceFor2: {
        $toDouble: "$PriceFor2"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iFstQTy0vCe)